# password in c programming, where do i place the function call for another function if the password is correct

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

char pw[25],ch;
int i;
 main()
{


        printf("\n\nEnter password");
        while(1)
        {
        if(i<0)
        i=0;
        ch=getch();
        if(ch==13)
        break;
        if(ch==8) 
        {
        putch('\b');
        putch(NULL);
        putch('\b');
        -i;
        continue;
        }
        pw[i++]=ch;
        ch='*';
        putch(ch);
        }
        pw[i]='\0';
        printf("\n\n%s",pw);


    getch();
}
```

Comment: So, what's the question? You've just stated an intent to do something...

Comment: why closed? it's a real question; and @xil3 the intent and the implicit "howto?" should make it clear what he's asking; why to close it so swiftly instead of inviting the user to edit it and to make it more readable and understandable?! on this site they happen things I really _can't_ understand

Comment: @xil3 I was not saying you did, I can read the list of "closed by"! I am just saying that the question, even though not too much explicit, is there already.

Answer (score 2):

This requirement usually means you want to ensure that casual passers-by cannot see what the user typed as a password by accident.  This might be by turning off the echo (this is what Unix usually does) or by echoing asterisks or something similar instead of the actual characters entered by the user.

The C standard alone does not help here.  You have to define the environment in which you are going to be running.  The techniques used in a GUI application are different from those used in a command line application.

Many versions of Unix provide a `getpass()` function, but it is not defined in POSIX.  As mentioned, it saves the terminal mode, turns off echoing, reads characters (normally discarding anything after the 8th character) and then reinstates the terminal mode before returning.